# Pdfkit with Wkhtmltopdf hang on Mac

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, wkhtmltopdf, pdfkit

I am trying to use PDFkit with `wkhtmltopdf` on mac but unfortunately, it is stuck or get hang and kept loading.

This successfully generates the pdf when ran manually from terminal `wkhtmltopdf http://google.com google.pdf`

I have tried all the possible solutions available on StackOverflow and I am not sure how I debug this issue.

I am successfully generating reports using `wkhtmltopdf` and pdfkit gem on Ubuntu but unfortunately, I am unable to generate pdf on Mac using pdfkit.

Suggestions, please

```
⇒  ruby -v
ruby 2.1.1p76 (2014-02-24 revision 45161) [x86_64-darwin17.0]

⇒  which ruby
/Users/mac/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.1/bin/ruby

⇒  which wkhtmltopdf
/usr/local/bin/wkhtmltopdf

⇒  wkhtmltopdf --version
wkhtmltopdf 0.12.4 (with patched qt)

⇒  brew config

HOMEBREW_VERSION: 1.5.13
ORIGIN: https://github.com/Homebrew/brew
HEAD: 0f4e22e28d3b65a6c8dbb0f270bb6d262a2429d6
Last commit: 3 days ago
Core tap ORIGIN: https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-core
Core tap HEAD: dc57a79d6c422c2052df8b33a1782a43cc1cfd53
Core tap last commit: 7 hours ago
HOMEBREW_PREFIX: /usr/local
HOMEBREW_AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID: set
HOMEBREW_AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY: set
CPU: quad-core 64-bit haswell
Homebrew Ruby: 2.3.3 => /usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Homebrew/vendor/portable-ruby/2.3.3/bin/ruby
GCC-4.2: build 5666
Clang: 9.0 build 900
Git: 2.11.0 => /usr/local/bin/git
Curl: 7.54.0 => /usr/bin/curl
Perl: /usr/local/bin/perl => /usr/local/Cellar/perl/5.24.0_1/bin/perl
Python: /usr/local/bin/python => /usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.13/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin/python2.7
Ruby: /Users/mac/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.1/bin/ruby
Java: N/A
macOS: 10.13.1-x86_64
Xcode: 9.2
CLT: 9.2.0.0.1.1510905681
X11: N/A
```

PDFkit Configurations in the initializer

```
PDFKit.configure do |config|
  config.default_options = {
    :encoding      => "UTF-8",
    #:page_width    => '14mm',
    #:page_height    => '14mm',
    :page_size     => 'Letter',
    :zoom          => 0.75,
    :margin_top    => '0.5in',
    :margin_right  => '0.5in',
    :margin_bottom => '0.7in',
    :margin_left   => '0.5in',
    :load_error_handling => 'ignore'
  }
end
```

In Application.rb

```
require 'pdfkit'
config.middleware.use PDFKit::Middleware, :print_media_type => true
```

Thank you

Comment: do you have any error messages?  how are you running this, from a console? inside a script?

Comment: @lacostenycoder i wish to have error messages or logs. It just get stucked.

Comment: Can you test with a newer version of ruby with rvm?  Also, is it possible you have any firewall running that could be blocking execution?

Comment: no firewall is running -- and tested it with ruby-2.3.3 also but no luck

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My bad just posting it for some other noob like me -- on production I was using Unicorn but locally i was trying to run it with Webrick and webrick get stuck when it has 2 requests at once while unicorn handle it.

Answer (score 1):

Works fine for me on MacOS.  Can you please post outputs of the following:

```
ruby -v
which ruby
which wkhtmltopdf
wkhtmltopdf --version
```

Hopefully you're using homebrew, if so output

```
brew config
```

Let's see what's going on here.

Make sure there are no stuck processes

```
ps aux | grep wkhtmltopdf
```

Try this

```
PDFKit.configure do |config|
  config.wkhtmltopdf = '/usr/local/bin/wkhtmltopdf'
  config.default_options = {
    :encoding      => "UTF-8",
    :page_size     => 'Letter',
    :zoom          => 0.75,
    :margin_top    => '0.5in',
    :margin_right  => '0.5in',
    :margin_bottom => '0.7in',
    :margin_left   => '0.5in',
    :load_error_handling => 'ignore'
  }
end
```

See https://github.com/pdfkit/pdfkit#configuration

```
# in application.rb(Rails3+) or environment.rb(Rails2)
require 'pdfkit'
config.middleware.use PDFKit::Middleware
```

Also in development you may need to run a multi-threaded server i.e. unicorn

https://github.com/pdfkit/pdfkit#troubleshooting

Comment: no stuck process but here is the command that is trying to run 
`/usr/local/bin/wkhtmltopdf --encoding UTF-8 --page-size Letter --zoom 0.75 --margin-top 0.5in --margin-right 0.5in --margin-bottom 0.7in --margin-left 0.5in --print-media-type --footer-html http://localhost:3000/pdf/footer --quiet - -`

Comment: how did you get this output?

Comment: try to comment out  `:load_error_handling => 'ignore' `